# Dynamics CRM 2011 Scheduled Report to Record Owner

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Our sales people would like to be emailed a weekly report for any new leads that have come in. Each sales person would be set as the owner of the lead and a flag field would be created indicating whether it is a new lead. I would like to create a workflow that would email each sales person their new leads for that week. I know how to create a recurring workflow in CRM, but cannot come up with a way to email a report to each sales person. I thought pre-filtering in SSRS for each sales person, but I'm not sure how to do that. Does anyone have any suggestions, links, etc on how to accomplish this? Even if this can't be created as a workflow, is there any other way to accomplish this even if there has to be a couple manual steps?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dynamics CRM 2011 On Premise then you could look into using "Schedule Report" this will allow you to create a report (and set the parameters for a particular staff member. They will then get an email sent to them.

The following link will provide some more details.
http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/06/29/report-scheduling-and-email-subscription-in-crm-2011/

My only issue is I don't think you can have one report and change the parameters per user (Meaning you would have to have one scheduled report per sales person which depending on the amount of sales people could be a real pain!)

NOTE: Schedule Report is not available in CRM Online